# How to prove that $\int \int _{\Omega} \frac{\sin(x)\sin(y) dx dy}{(x+y)^{p}}$ is divergent

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Consider $\displaystyle \int \int _{\Omega} \frac{\sin(x)\sin(y) dx dy}{(x+y)^{p}}$, where $\Omega = \{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2 : x+y \ge 1\}$.
 Now we need to prove that integral is divergent for all $p \in \mathbb{R}$.

My attempt :
if it diverges , we need to find an $\{\Omega_{n} \}$ and $\{\Phi_{n}\}$, such as $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \int\int_{\Omega_{n}} \frac{\sin(x)\sin(y)}{(x+y)^{p}} = \infty \ne const = \lim_{n \to \infty} \int \int _{\Phi_{n}}\frac{\sin(x)\sin(y)}{(x+y)^{p}}$.

Let's simplify this function : $\sin(x)\sin(y) = \frac{1}{2}(\cos(x-y) -\cos(x+y))$, so let $x-y = u$ and $x+y = v$, so $\mathfrak{J} = \frac{1}{2}$ (Jacobian). So we have (with no respect to Jacobian) : $$\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{1}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{\cos(u)-\cos(v)}{v^{p}}$$

Now let's $-2\pi n\le u \le 2\pi n$, so we will have $$\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{-2\pi n}^{2\pi n} \int_{1}^{\infty}f(u,v) = \lim_{n \to \infty} 4\pi  n\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(v)}{v^{p}}$$

Now there I'm stuck , how can we show two $\Omega_{n}$ and $\Phi_{n}$ such as they have different values.

Comment: I have changed the formatting of the title so as to
[make it take up less vertical space](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9686/290189) --
this is a policy to ensure that the scarce space on the main
page is distributed evenly over the questions.
See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9730)
for more information. Please take this into consideration for future
questions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you going to tell us anything about $p?$

Comment: @zhw. we need to show that answer doesn't depend of $p$

Comment: There still are some things to fix: many integrals do not have differentials attached (so it is hard to understand where the variables range) and there is a $\lim_{n\to +\infty}$ of something that does not depend on $n$. Additionally, is $$\Omega=\{(x,y)\color{red}{\in\mathbb{R}^+\times\mathbb{R}^+}:x+y\geq 1\}$$ or something else?

Comment: OK, then tell us about $p$ in the statement please. Also tell us what it means for such a double integral to be divergent. We need a precise definition.

Comment: Does the region of integration really extend over values of $x$ and $y$ such that $x+y<0$?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio $\{(x,y) \subset \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \}

Comment: $\texttt{Mathematica 10.0.0.0}$ yields $\color{red}{0}\,,\ \forall\ p$. Maybe, It should be checked with a $recent$ version !!!.

Comment: @FelixMarin I checked it on my Mathematica and there was "integral is diverges"

Comment: @zhw. Consider a $\{ \Omega_{n} \} $ such as $\Omega_{n} \subset \Omega_{n+1}$ and $\{x+y \ge 1} \subset \{\Omega_{n}\}$ then this integral converges if limit of integral on this Omega is the same for all $\{\Omega_{n} \}$ from previous sentence

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio actually in terms of this task the question is so : is it possible to parametrize $[0 , \infty)$ to get the last integral give us something like $1/n^{1-\epsilon}$ and  $1/n$ to get the factor $4n$ be negligible or not

Comment: Looks like you're being sloppy. You want $\Omega_ n \subset \Omega_{n+1} \subset \cdots $ and $\Omega = \cup \Omega_n$ don't you?

Comment: @openspace I could imagine that. My version is pretty old. I'll change it in may when I'll go back to USA.

Comment: @zhw. yes, that's I'm want

Comment: Aren't you just trying to show the integral is not absolutely convergent?

Comment: @zhw. No, I haven't tried it yet