# Investigate the convergence of $\iint_{x+y\ge1}\frac{\sin x\sin y}{(x+y)^p}\,dx\,dy$

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence

Investigate the convergence of the improper integral
$$\iint\limits_{x+y\ge1}\dfrac{\sin x\sin y}{(x+y)^p}\,dxdy$$

Let $u=x+y$, $v= x-y$, then
$$\frac14\int\limits_1^{+\infty}du\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\dfrac{\cos v-\cos u}{u^p}\,dv=\frac12\int\limits_1^{+\infty}du\int\limits_0^{+\infty}\dfrac{\cos v-\cos u}{u^p}\,dv.$$
Let's move from the double integral to the repeated integral
$$\lim\limits_{k\to+\infty}\frac12\int\limits_1^k\dfrac{du}{u^p}\int\limits_0^k(\cos v-\cos u)\,dv=\frac12\lim\limits_{k\to+\infty}\left(\sin k\int\limits_1^k\dfrac{du}{u^p}-k\int\limits_1^k\dfrac{\cos u}{u^p}\right)\!.$$
What to do next?

Comment: What is your work on this homework ?

Comment: You could use maybe relationship $\sin(x)\sin(y)=\frac12(\cos(x-y)-\cos(x+y))$.

Comment: I wouldn't use your bracketing $-A \leq B \leq A$ which is too "brute force", bringing in automaticaly divergent integrals.

Comment: I just saw that this question has been asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2691306), without answer. But see the comment (in red letters) of Jack d'Aurizio.

Answer (score 2):

By a change of variables
$$\begin{eqnarray*} \iint_{\substack{x+y\geq 1\\ x,y\geq 0}}\frac{\sin(x)\sin(y)}{(x+y)^p}\,dx\,dy &=& \int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{s^p}\int_{0}^{s}\sin(x)\sin(s-x)\,dx\,ds\\ &=& \frac{1}{2}\int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(s)-s\cos(s)}{s^p}\,ds.\end{eqnarray*} $$
By Dirichlet's test the integral $\int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(s)}{s^p}\,ds$ is convergent for any $p>0$ and absolutely convergent for any $p>1$. 
For the same reason the integral $\int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{\cos(s)}{s^{p-1}}\,ds$ is convergent for any $p>1$ and absolutely convergent for any $p>2$.

Comment: So the integral absolutely converges when p>2?

Comment: Why $$\iint\limits_{x+y\ge1}\dfrac{\sin x\sin y}{(x+y)^p}\,dxdy=\int\limits_1^{+\infty}\dfrac1{s^p}\int\limits_0^s\sin x\sin(s-x)\,dxds?$$

Comment: @КириллКолокольцев: just set $x+y=s$ and keep $x$ as $x$.

Comment: why does $x$ change from $0$ to $s$? I think, that $x$ change from $-\infty$ to $\infty$.

Comment: @КириллКолокольцев: right, I assumed that the integration range actually was $x+y\geq 1$ with $x,y\geq 0$. If the second constraint does not hold, these lines still give necessary conditions for the (absolute) integrability.

Comment: but this integral diverges